# MSMQ QMThreadNo and CleanupInterval

Tags: .net, client-server, msmq, nservicebus

I have a client-server application that utilises MSMQ and NServiceBus for messaging. During some recent testing, clients were left inactive for some time and unexpected behaviour of MSMQ was discovered:

- MSMQ has a default number of threads that it uses to process queues
  (set in registry as QMThreadNo). When queues are left in a dormant
  state for an extended period of time, they accumulate a large number
  of messages. These large queues hold onto the limited number of
  threads that MSMQ has for longer than usual and therefore does takes
  longer to process the queues that are actually active.

  - **It is possible to set the registry entry to a higher thread count.**
- Clients that are not sending/receiving messages for a set period of
  time (set in registry as the CleanupInterval) will change to an
  “Inactive” state and eventually their queues will be deleted until a
  message is sent from that client, forcing the recreation of the
  queues.

  - **The CleanupInterval can be changed from its default of 5 minutes to a much longer amount of time.**

Has anyone encountered these issues before? And if so, what possible solutions are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate between Outgoing Queues or destination Queues.

> "When queues are left in a dormant state for an extended period of
>   time, they accumulate a large number of messages. These large queues
>   hold onto the limited number of threads that MSMQ has for longer than
>   usual and therefore does takes longer to process the queues that are
>   actually active."

MSMQ has a thread pool for outgoing queues. MSMQ will try and connect the outgoing queue to the destination and deliver the messages. If you have, for example, 1,000 outgoing queues then it will take some time for MSMQ to cycle through all of them.
This has nothing to do with destination queues.

I don't quite understand how the number of messages in an outgoing queue will affect thread usage. There will only be one thread in use on a particular queue at any one time.

An active queue has a thread - as otherwise it wouldn't be active. I assume we are talking about the Status of the queue in Computer Management here.

> Clients that are not sending/receiving messages for a set period of
>   time (set in registry as the CleanupInterval) will change to an
>   “Inactive” state and eventually their queues will be deleted until a
>   message is sent from that client, forcing the recreation of the
>   queues.

Again, this is Outgoing queues only. Outgoing queues are dynamically created by MSMQ on demand. They are deleted, if empty, after the CleanupInterval. This is perfectly normal and how MSMQ frees up resources.

Like any product, MSMQ may need optimisation to meet your needs. If you want to change the registry values, go ahead.

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: *Thanks for your reply John.
To clear up any ambiguity, we have a partially connected client/server application which requires real time messaging. We have read in some of your articles that MSMQ is not originally designed for real time but can be configured to do so.
Our issue is that the outgoing queue on the client is set to "Connected". However the outgoing queue on the server is set to "Inactive" for up to 30 minutes which is inefficient for our 'real time' system. After this period of time the outgoing queue on the server is set back to "Connected" and messages flow as normal again.

Comment: We have modified QMThreadNo to 3000, but have not noticed a change in progressing from inactive to connected. We also have modified the WaitTime to 5000 in a hope that it would decrease the time between processing different threads.

Comment: So you have proved that it isn't a threading issue. Unless you have many, many outgoing queues then I wouldn't expect it to be anyway.

Comment: it's the time is takes for the outgoing queues on the server to go from "inactive" to "connected" that's the problem. at the moment the server has approx. 40 outgoing queues and we are noticing delays up to 10 minutes.

Comment: If you have an adequate number of threads (and 3,000 should be enough!) then either the value isn't entered in the registry correctly (and so being ignored) or there is a network level connection problem. Each outgoing queue should connect at most 5 seconds after a message is created in it (as you have set WaitTime to 5,000 ms). I would recommend looking at network traces to see if there are connectivity issues (name resolution delays is always a good one).

Comment: It must be something to do with connectivity, however some connections are over VPN, the others are over local network. name resolution shouldn't be an issue as IP leases are 8 days.

Comment: "name resolution shouldn't be an issue as IP leases are 8 days." No, that is incorrect. The IP lease length is almost irrelevant in this context. Name resolution issues are much more complicated than that.